# suggestion on tkinter for python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

first of all my apology if you find this topic redundant....but I need some specific answers from you..thats why I have made this.

I have recently start learning tkinter for python. But I cant decide which route to take . Every tutorial comes up with a new approach which is confusing. So I need to know:

1.Which part of tkinter should I study first ??

2.what knowledge should I have before start tkinter ??

3.is there any book or tutorial where the top to bottom structure is documented ??

4.whats your suggestion for me to learn the tkinter in detail ??

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Q1.- Get familiar with basic containers and widgets and their properties, then understand the diffferent methods to layout your widgets, and finally study how the command propertie and events work for connecting your program logic with your widgets.

Q2.- Tkinter does not requires any special background except for Python itself.
Tkinter is often used in an "non OOP" mode (no classes defined, etc). This is OK for very simple things, but I recommend to define your frame in a class and use OOP to structure your application widgets and behavior. So better if you are familiar with OOP. Suggestions in Q3 use this approach.

Q3.- My suggestions in the order indicated:
1) [Tkinter 8.4 reference: a GUI for Python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/) (John W. Shipman, 2010)
2) [Thinking in TkInter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/) (Stephen Ferg, 2005) and references herein

Q4.- write your GUIs, read others code, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

thanks man, tkinter 8.4 reference was quite useful.
I also found [Core Python Programming](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CGUQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbulaohu.org%2Fjueduibaomi%2FCore%2BPython%2BProgramming%2B(2nd%2BEdition).pdf&ei=eyCrT9evBJDJrAeJ3oTzAQ&usg=AFQjCNGl0vJhjb_wIt6Pe6e3xLiusxIJUA&sig2=dLGu72NpV1XjsfY3qfCvvA)  was very useful to learn the very basics of tkinter.